# Get Google Maps take into account the CSS before setting height/width of InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to place some text and form elements into a Google Maps `InfoWindow`. Problem I'm having is once I got beyond formatting the text to adding padding, floats and such like, the `InfoWindow` loses the proportions/sizes and thus it's too small and produces scrollbars.

Setting the outer div within the `InfoWindow` to a set size with `display: block;` doesn't work. So it seems like it ignores the CSS I'm setting beyond `font-size`.

Anybody know of a way to get Google Maps take into account the CSS of elements in the `InfoWindow` before setting it's height/width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking to a [colleague](http://flav36rs.com/) about the issue, it turns out that it was due to the CSS being nested within another class. As I had the all the type attributes set within the root of the CSS doc, they where being accounted for.

So taking the inner `div` CSS attributes of the `InfoWindow` content and putting them in the root of the CSS allowed Google Maps to work out the actual height of the `InfoWindow`.

Comment: Previously JQuery-UI button in an InfoWindow styled just fine. E.g. *new google.maps.InfoWindow('<a class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" href="#RBMonitoring"><span class="ui-button-text">RBMonitoring</span></a>');*  But now the css class ignored; other functionality ok.  I read posts that maps v3.14 broke a lot of styling.  Any clue to this that does not refer me to InfoBubble or InfoBox or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

The size of your `InfoWindows` are determined by the size of the map that they are in, so a smaller map with a big `InfoWindow` will cause scroll bars, and vice versa.

The `InfoWindow` will always be fit to the map, so if you want to make your `InfoWindow` smaller to include scroll bars (though i don't know why you would want to) then change the size of your map. 
If you want to make it bigger then do the opposite.

Comment: The issue isn't to make the `InfoWindow` smaller to include scroll bars, but when I do make it smaller by including floats to remove some white space (also making it shorter) and add padding to certain text to make room for background elements, the `InfoWindow` doesn't take the extra CSS into account (ignoring it so it seems).